# Is there some out of box feature in sharePoint to join two or more SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to join multiple SharePoint list based on Lookup Id (or based on some common column) like how we do in Sql Server, Is there some out of box feature available in SharePoint 2013, if not then how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPD to achieve this, OOB **Data View Web Part** is what you'll need to configure. Create two datasources, set the link type, and use webpart to show a combination of both. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-Data-View-f9898d20-a5ab-4973-9d16-9f4e4c088ae1

> Under *Select the link type that best represents the relationship
>   between the selected sources*, click *Join the contents of the data
>   sources by using the Data Source Details to insert data views and
>   joined subviews*.
>
> You have two options: merge or join. You merge data when you have
>   different data sources with the same fields that you want to merge
>   into a single data source. You join data when you have two different
>   data sources that have a field in common that associates one data
>   source with another data source.

Also, http://sympmarc.com/2009/07/24/the-right-way-to-join-two-lists-in-a-dvwp/ might be useful

Comment: I have followed this blog 
[link](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/perform-joins-between-sharepoint-60009.html)
I have created the Data Source, but i am not able to view it on site Page.
How to configure this datasource into my sitepage

Comment: Would you try this http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2009/05/12/data-view-web-part-the-basics-insert-a-dvwp-on-your-page-aspx/ and point a webpart to a ds you've already created?

Comment: This is for 2013: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/12/sharepoint-2013-add-dataview-webpart-with-sharepoint-designer-2013/. You'll see List View Tools in ribbon, ds is configured there